# Repeat rows of table based on other table rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 has below data:

[image: Table 1 has below data]

Table 2 has below data:

[image: Table 2 has below Data]

I want the data as below:

[image]

It looks like cross join and left join . The below query I tried is not working.

```
SELECT cr.*, e.*
from COSTING_RESULTS cr 
     ELEMENTS e
WHERE cr.element_name = e.element_name(+)
```

The requirement is for every assignment numbers I need 3 rows in output matching 3 element. Can anyone help me with the query. I am using Oracle SQL.

Comment: So the Element Name in Table 1 is irrelevant? Regardless of what it has you still want 3 records, one for each Element Name in Table 2?

Comment: Please read the following then edit your question; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Oracle syntax from the previous millennium, did you learn it then or now? Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to (understandable and portable) outer join if needed!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you want the cartesian product between distinct `assignment_number` and `element_name`, so:

```
SELECT t1.Assignment_Number, t2.element_name 
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT Assignment_Number FROM COSTING_RESULTS) as t1,        
   Elements t2;
```

There is no need to establish a relationship between the two tables with a WHERE or ON clause.

You can also take @MatBailie and @jarlh's very good, but rudely stated advice to use the `CROSS JOIN` keyword.

Comment: `,` instead of `CROSS JOIN`!?!?!?

Comment: I can't bring my self to vote for anyone that uses pre-ANSI92 syntax :( ***(Teaching others bad habits is a very poor behavior.)***

Comment: @JNevill  In COSTING_RESULTS table along with assignment number I have other columns. The below query is giving Cartesian product which is wrong for my requirement. SELECT  t1.Assignment_Number, petf.base_element_name e_name
 FROM pay_element_types_f petf
  , (SELECT DISTINCT Assignment_Number
    , person_number
    , FTE
    FROM COSTING_RESULTS
    ) t1  
 WHERE 1 = 1 
 AND petf.base_element_name IN ('Medical ER Results'
         , 'Basic Life ER Results'
         , 'US_SOCIAL_SECURITY_EMPLOYER_TAX'
         )

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition to use a cross join is correct.

The step you're missing is to ***reduce*** the first table to just the unique assignment numbers.

That avoids having to work out if a row does or does not need joining, they'll ***all*** need joining.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT assignment_number FROM costing_results
) 
  cr
CROSS JOIN 
  elements   e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT t1.assignment_number,
       t2.element_name
FROM   table2 t2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
       PARTITION BY (t1.assignment_number)
       ON (t1.element_name = t2.element_name)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (assignment_number, element_name) AS
SELECT 'E11111',   'Basic Life' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E11111',   'Medical'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E11111',   'US Social'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E11111-2', 'Basic Life' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E11111-2', 'Medical'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E11111-2', 'US Social'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E11111-3', 'Basic Life' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (element_name) AS
SELECT 'Basic Life'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Medical'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'US Social'    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER | ELEMENT_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| E11111 | Basic Life |
| E11111 | Medical |
| E11111 | US Social |
| E11111-2 | Basic Life |
| E11111-2 | Medical |
| E11111-2 | US Social |
| E11111-3 | Basic Life |
| E11111-3 | Medical |
| E11111-3 | US Social |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PPj__hOU)

Comment: Hi @MTO , I am not good with using 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' for left Join , I always write queries using (+) symbol for outer joins, How can we convert this SQL format I use?

Comment: @RaghavendraM You cannot, `PARTITION`ed joins are ANSI syntax and there is no equivalent legacy comma-join syntax.